# Map and comparison in python

Tags: python, lambda, functional-programming, map-function

Say I have a list:

```py
foo_list = ["foo", None, "bar", 1, 0, None]
```

I want to transform this list into a boolean list saying which elements are `None`, like

```py
results = [False, True, False, False, False, True]
```

A simple `map` and `lambda` will do:

```py
list(map(lambda a: a==None, foo_list))
```

but I want to know if I can remove the lambda, and make it even simpler, something along the lines of:

```py
list(map((==None), foo_list))
```

which obviously throws an error, but other functional languages often allow operators as functions, and technically this function isn't even curried (since it has all the arguments it needs).

Edit: I am aware of list comprehensions in `Python`, and that this could be solved as `[(a==None) for a in foo_list]`, but that is not my question.

Comment: In FP an operator is just a function in infix notation with a predefined precedence and associativity. You have partially applied `==` in your pseudo-code example, so yes, it is curried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’d say the list comprehension is the Pythonic way, but if you really want to, you could do

```
import functools
import operator
foo_list = ["foo", None, "bar", 1, 0, None]
print(list(map(functools.partial(operator.is_, None), foo_list)))
```